# Are nested <a> links legal?

Tags: html

I'd like to nest some links inside each other in my website's banner, something like:

```
<a href="/" class="hero-image">
    <a href="/some-page" class="navigation-button">Some page</a>
    <a href="/some-other-page" class="navigation-button">Some other page</a>
    <a href="/yet-another-page" class="navigation-button">Yet another page</a>
</a>
```

and have the page-specific inner links show up overlaid on top of the big banner link that returns the user to the site's homepage.

I know that wrapping block content in an `<a>` is [legal in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/1709587), so is this legal too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.

Two parts of section [4.5.1 The `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) in the HTML 5 spec together forbid this:

> ## 4.5.1 The a element
>
> #### [Categories:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-categories)
>
> [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).
>   [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).
>   ***[Interactive content](http://Interactive%20content).***
>   [Palpable content](http://Palpable%20content).
>
> ...
>
> #### [Content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model):
>
> [Transparent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent), but ***there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant***.

(emphasis mine).

Since `<a>` elements cannot contain interactive content, but themselves *are* interactive content, it follows that an `<a>` element cannot contain another `<a>` element.

What's more, this doesn't work in real browsers. If you try out the HTML from the question ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/effhxb2s/)) in a browser, you will observe that the browser makes all four `<a>` elements *siblings*, rather than letting the inner ones descend from the outer ones.

Comment: It won't work *in the `text/html` serialization*. Nested a elements can be *invalidly* constructed in the `application/xhtml+xml` serialization or by JavaScript. If you do however, browsers do not treat them interoperably, so that clicking on the stack on `a` elements will navigate the page to the outer element's link in some browsers and to the inner elements link in other browsers.

Comment: why are nested interactive content not allowed in HTML ? are there any usability issues?

Answer (score 4):

Nesting anchor links are not allowed. The reason is posted in [another answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34733392/3597276).

However, to achieve the link set-up described in the question, you could do something like this:

**HTML** ([adheres to standards](https://validator.w3.org/))

```
<nav id="main-container">
    <a href="/" class="hero-image">Link 1</a>
    <div id="overlaying-container">
        <a href="/some-page" class="navigation-button">Link 2</a>
        <a href="/some-other-page" class="navigation-button">Link 3</a>
        <a href="/yet-another-page" class="navigation-button">Link 4</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#overlaying-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
}

.navigation-button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ouyvqagx/2/)